# How to run solr query with imcomplete last term?

Tags: solr

I am trying to write a query, such that for any of the following queries

1. 
2. `Elephant`
3. `Elephant is the bigge`
4. `Elephant is the biggest land mammal.`

Solr should be able to return following result
`Elephant is the biggest land mammal.`

I've tried following two methods

1. `field:"query*"`
2. `field:"Elephant is the" && field:"bigge*"`

First query isn't able to handle the last incomplete words like in the query `Elephant is the bigge`. While second query is able to handle it, it isn't always reliable. Is there a better approach to it.

**PS:** I am using text_general for that field if that's helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a common query against that field and the field content is exactly matching a prefix of your query, consider using a `string` field instead - or a TextField with a `KeywordTokenizer` and a `LowercaseFilter` if you want it to be case insensitive - it'll be more efficient than trying to make `text_general` work as you want.

There might be a few issues with stopwords, but I think the [ComplexPhraseQueryParser](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/other-parsers.html#complex-phrase-query-parser) should work as you want to:

```
q={!complexphrase inOrder=true}field:"Elephant is the bigge*"
```

Make sure to append `*` to the last term in your query so that the last term is used as a wildcard.

You should also be aware that wildcards are special in Lucene/Solr, as they can't use all the regular filters in an analysis chain as defined for a field - so you might get surprising results when you have stemming/synonyms/etc. for that field. In that case it's better to use a dedicated field type that you can do a prefix search against, as mentioned at the start.